# RabbitMQ: how to create a consumer that is always listening

Tags: c#, rabbitmq

I need to create a consumer that is always running and listening queued messages in .NET Framework (4.8), NOT CORE!

The next code is the core of the job.
RabbitHelper wraps some operations such as create connection and so on...

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        RabbitHelper.Init("host", 123, "user", "password", "Provider", "virtual");

        const string queueName = "MYQUEUE";

        var consumer = new AsyncEventingBasicConsumer(RabbitHelper.channel);
        consumer.Received += Consumer_Received;

        RabbitHelper.channel.BasicConsume(queueName, true, consumer);

    }

    private static async Task Consumer_Received(object sender, BasicDeliverEventArgs eevent)
    {
        var message = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(eevent.Body.ToArray());

        Console.WriteLine($"Begin processing {message}");

        await Task.Delay(250);

        Console.WriteLine($"End processing {message}");
    }
}
```

Comment: I have not worked with RabbitMQ, but the least you would need to do it have something like Console.ReadLine(), to make sure the console does not just close. In the end, a Windows Service might be the better choice than an always open console window.

Comment: I used TopShelf, in the end. The job is served as service and it's testable just pressing F5!